# How to authenticate an api of reqres.in in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, api, authentication

I got a simple task in which I have to implement login of any website with basic authentication in angular. I have got API link for register and login both. I am a beginner in angular don't know how to use API.
API links 
for register[enter link description here](http://reqres.in/api/login)

for log in [enter link description here](http://reqres.in/api/login)

Comment: You want to authenticate your API Request on server side?

Comment: Yes by the http.post method of reqres.in (public api) but i am not getting any output for reqres.in/api.login

Comment: @WasifKhan I have to do this[link](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2014/05/26/angularjs-basic-http-authentication-example) task instead  of dummy i have to use reqres.in/api/login

Comment: I studied little bit about reqres.in, it is dummy API for your front end right? and the links about login and register are same, please post register one as well.

Comment: @WasifKhan i have given same link